# Surface automatic UV mapping in THREEJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

Is it possible to use some big texture to "cover" some surface mesh to achieve an effect with THREEJS like this:
[image]

, without manual UV mapping? (I have TIN and point cloud as "surface source")

[interactive demo](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=image-to-bar3d&gl=1)

I need it for interactive 3D heatmap which should operate huge InSAR pointcloud dataset (I use points buffer geometry with custom displacement attribute and LUT  now).

Comment: In the example you show, normalizing X/Z coordinates to the range 0-1 would give you good enough UVs. Vertices with the same Y height would all have the same color.

Comment: What is "TIN" in this context?

Comment: TIN here is a surface mesh (point triangulation). Looks that I really need to calculate UVs for each face by X,Z and forget about Y